# Custom attribute in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a site in wordpress with differents menus bars, but I need to put in a specific page a type of menu. I would like to have a tag or attribute called :

Menu 1
Menu 2
Menu 3

and I should to choose what menu I want to show in my page.

How could I create an custom attribute or tag for a page ?

P.D. : Is for pages not for posts

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: If you're building a custom theme, I'd suggest altering your template files before bringing in a plugin. If you're just setting up a site though, by all means, use the plugins in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

On WordPress when you create a menu it automatically catches a unique ID. SO you can call by that ID. So simply you can pass by custom JS.

**Plugin Way**

You can use a plugin to choose which menu will be shown on which page. 
Something like this: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-menu/
OR
https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-specific-menu-items/

Try that hope it will help you.